# How to set Android TeeChart Border Color

Tags: android, teechart

I use Steema TeeChart JAVA for Android to create a Chart.
With the following code i tried to change the color of the charts border, but it effects nothing.

```
public void setBorderColor(Color borderColor){

    tChart.getWalls().getRight().setColor(borderColor);
    tChart.getWalls().getLeft().setColor(borderColor);
    tChart.getWalls().getBottom().setColor(borderColor);
    tChart.getWalls().getBack().setColor(borderColor);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the pen color `getPen()` instead of changing the wall color. Ie:

```
public void setBorderColor(Color borderColor){

    tChart.getWalls().getRight().getPen().setColor(borderColor);
    tChart.getWalls().getLeft().getPen().setColor(borderColor);
    tChart.getWalls().getBottom().getPen().setColor(borderColor);
    tChart.getWalls().getBack().getPen().setColor(borderColor);
}
```

You may be interested on also changing the axes pen color. Ie:

```
public void setBorderColor(Color borderColor){

    tChart.getWalls().getRight().getPen().setColor(borderColor);
    tChart.getWalls().getLeft().getPen().setColor(borderColor);
    tChart.getWalls().getBottom().getPen().setColor(borderColor);
    tChart.getWalls().getBack().getPen().setColor(borderColor);

    tChart.getAxes().getLeft().getAxisPen().setColor(borderColor);
    tChart.getAxes().getBottom().getAxisPen().setColor(borderColor);
}
```

Comment: Thanks its working great. Can i ask you an other question? Is there a method for changing the distance between Axis and Axis title?

Comment: This is a bit more complicate. It would be better if you opened a new question for this.

Comment: I postedt he new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31027660/change-distance-between-axis-title-and-axis-in-android-teechart

Comment: I saw it. I'll reply you there asap